# I'm trying to install parcel with npm and I keep getting this error. I am using the latest version of vscode

Tags: npm

```
 error code 1
1214 error path C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder (2)\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\17-Modern-JS-Modules-Tooling\starter\node_modules\lmdb
1215 error command failed
1216 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp-build-optional-packages
1217 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
1217 error gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
1217 error gyp info using node@16.16.0 | win32 | ia32
1217 error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.1 found at "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS 
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS - not found
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS 
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
1217 error gyp ERR! find VS 
1217 error gyp ERR! configure error 
1217 error gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
1217 error gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
1217 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
1217 error gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
1217 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
1217 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
1217 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
1217 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
1217 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
1217 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
1217 error gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
1217 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
1217 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
1217 error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder (2)\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\17-Modern-JS-Modules-Tooling\starter\node_modules\lmdb
1217 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
1217 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
1217 error gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) is not [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: Oh! Does everyone that use parcel have visual studio installed or it's just my PC

Comment: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/8152